# BeforeSave Validation with EF Code-FIrst

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm attempting to isolate my custom entity validation logic.

I see the following: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2009/07/20/tip-27-how-to-implement-beforesave-validation/

However when I attempt this:

```
public partial class ApplicationContext {
     public void Validate() 
  { 
    var stateEntries = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries( 
                              EntityState.Added | 
                              EntityState.Modified | 
                              EntityState.Deleted ) 
                      .Where(e => e.Entity is IValidingEntity);

    foreach (var stateEntry in stateEntries) 
    { 
        var entity = stateEntry.Entity as IValidingEntity; 
        entity.Validate(stateEntry.State); 
    }              
  }
}
```

I get `Cannot access non-static method GetObjectStateEntries in a static context`, where `ApplicationContext` is:

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext {}
```

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does the object being validated look like? Does it implement IValidatingEntity?

EDIT: The code you are referencing is from 2009 and incorrect with bugs. Use something like this in DbContext to override validation before save

```
protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary<object, object> items)
{
    var result = base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, items);
    // do your own validation here
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This occurs as a compile-time exception.